# How can I count the number of the same value on list in c#

Tags: c#

Here's the code:

```
List<string> Listahan = new List<string>();
Listahan.Add("TEST1");
Listahan.Add("TEST2");
Listahan.Add("TEST3");
Listahan.Add("TEST4");
Listahan.Add("TEST5");
Listahan.Add("TEST5");
Listahan.Add("TEST1");
```

Then what I want is when I enter TEST1 on my textbox it will output it's count which is 2.
Thank in advance.

Answer (score 7):

```
string textboxVal = "TEST1";    
int testOccurence = Listahan.Count(str => str == textboxVal);
```

If you are using **.NET 2.0** and don't use [LINQBridge](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/linqbridge.aspx):

```
int testOccurence = Listahan.FindAll(delegate (string str) { return str == textboxVal;})
                            .Count;
```

some notes: it might be the case, that you may also need case insensitive search. For example user can enter `"test1"` and receive meaningful results. You can use next code to achieve this:

```
Listahan.Count(str => string.Equals(str, textboxVal, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
```

Answer (score 2):

You also can use `GroupBy` to count all the text first if you often access:

```
var dic = Listahan.GroupBy(x => x)
                  .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Count());

int count = dic["TEST1"]; //count of 'TEST1'
```

Comment: +1 for giving **O(1)** search solution, while my would require complexity of **O(n)**. It only requires to recreate or synchronize dictionary, when you add elements to the list, which might be acceptable.